# Border is shown in CardView in older API versions when cardCornerRadius is set

Tags: android

I use `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` in my app. If I specify a non zero `cardCornerRadius` to a card, a border is shown (color of the border is determined by `cardBackgroundColor` value specified) in API versions older than 20.

API level 21:
[image]

API level 19:
[image]

Here is my `CardView` layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#000"
    app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    ...........
    ...........
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

How can I get rid of this border while keeping corner radius?